# function: injective proof check

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification

Let the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = x^{2} - 3x-2$. Determine whether $f$ is one-to-one.

so I started by:

Let $f(a) = f(b)$ <-> $a=b$

$a^2 - 3a - 2$ = $b^2 - 3b - 2$

$a^2 - 3a = b^2 - 3b$ then I put the b's on the LHS, it became

$a^2-b^2-3a+3b =0$ , now did factoring

$(a+b)(a-b) - 3(a-b) = 0$ $\rightarrow$ $(a-b)(a+b-3) = 0$

this is where I am confused to do next $(a-b) = 0$ or $(a+b-3) = 0$ , for $a-b = 0$ is $a = b$ and for $a+b-3 =0$ is $a+b =3$ ...my question is how do I tell this is or isn't one to one function by going this route not by doing the factoring way $x(x-3)-2$ $x = 0,3$ the output for both values is $-2$ for the image, therefore isn't one-to-one.

Comment: It's clearly not injective by the quadratic formula since it has two roots.

Comment: if a+b=3 we can find infinite pairs (a,b) such that a is not equal to b hence not injective

Comment: You can use counter example

Comment: never mind, I found my mistake :)

Comment: first of all it can happen when a=b=1.5 , any way while solving xy=0 x=0 and y=o are considered to be independent equations or we should not use the result of one on another .(a-b)(a+b-3)=0 implies a=b or a+b=3 or we cannot say a has to be equal to b

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x^{2}-3x-2$, so by horizontal line test  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test
you can conclude that $f$ is not injective (one-to-one).